# Read from pipe even if the write end is closed

Tags: c, unix, pipe

my teacher said that if the writing end of a pipe is closed, the child process can no longer read from the read end of the pipe and a read would generate a BROKEN _PIPE error. However, I can't get this code to generate any error while reading on the closed tube :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wait.h>

int main(void) {
    int pipefd[2];
    char c;

    pipe(pipefd);

    if (fork() == 0) {
        close(pipefd[1]);
        sleep(5);
        // The parent has already closed pipefd[1]
        while (read(pipefd[0], &c, 1)) {
            printf("%c", c);
        }
        close(pipefd[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    close(pipefd[0]);

    char str[] = "foo";
    write(pipefd[1], str, 4);

    close(pipefd[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

The output on stdout after 5 seconds is `foo`. So what I understand is that closing the write end just add EOF after the characters already there and DOES NOT send EOF on any forthcoming read (so the child can read all the characters already sent). Am I right ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you have found out, your teacher is wrong.

You do not get a broken pipe "error" (which is actually a combination of a signal, `SIGPIPE`, and an error `EPIPE` if that is ignored), when you try to *read* from a broken pipe, but when you attempt to *write* to a broken pipe.

For Linux systems, you can read more about this [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html), or you can take a look at the BSD man page [pipe(2)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?pipe(2)).

Comment: Ok but the man page of pipe says that "if all file descriptors referring to the write end of a pipe have closed, then an attempt to read from the pipe will see end-of-file", but when I call read after the pipe is closed, I still get the remaining characters and not EOF, so will I get EOF only if the pipe is empty and therefore I can read all the pipe even if every write end of it is closed?

Comment: Yes, you get all the data that has already been written. Otherwise the writing process would need to somehow magically "know" when then client has finished reading.